# MassTransit help registering multiple sagas

Tags: entity-framework, masstransit, saga

I'm working on porting an old app to .net6, and ran into an issue with registrering multiple sagas with masstransit.

```
services.AddMassTransit<IProcessManagerBus>(busCfg =>
{
    busCfg.AddSagaStateMachine<OrderPM, OrderPMState>()
        .EntityFrameworkRepository<OrderPMState>(efConfig =>
        {
            efConfig.ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Optimistic;
            efConfig.DatabaseFactory(() => new OrderStateDbContext(configuration.GetConnectionString("DB")));
        });
    
    busCfg.AddSagaStateMachine<CsaLoginPM, CsaLoginPMState>()
        .EntityFrameworkRepository<CsaLoginPMState>(efConfig =>
        {
            efConfig.ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Optimistic;
            efConfig.DatabaseFactory(() => new CsaLoginStateDbContext(configuration.GetConnectionString("DB")));
        });
    
    busCfg.UsingRabbitMq((context, rabbitCfg) =>
    {
        rabbitCfg.UseJsonSerializer();
        rabbitCfg.Host(new Uri(configuration.GetValue<string>("messaging:pm-bus:host-address")), hostCfg =>
        {
            hostCfg.Username(configuration.GetValue<string>("messaging:pm-bus:username"));
            hostCfg.Password(configuration.GetValue<string>("messaging:pm-bus:password"));        
            
            rabbitCfg.ReceiveEndpoint(configuration.GetValue<string>("messaging:pm-bus:receive-queue"), epCfg =>
            {
                epCfg.PrefetchCount = 10;
                epCfg.UseRetry(retryConfig => retryConfig.Exponential(5, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
                
                epCfg.ConfigureSagas(context);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The OrderPMState works fine, but the CsaLoginPMState gives the following error when triggered: **System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type CsaLoginPMState is not part of the model for the current context.**

If I comment out the registration of the OrderPMState, the CsaLoginPMState works fine. I suspect, that the 2 sagas are using the same DbContext, despite being registered with their individual DbContext.

**OrderStateDbContext**

```
public class OrderStateDbContext : SagaDbContext
{
    public OrderStateDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<ISagaClassMap> Configurations
    {
        get { yield return new OrderPMStateMapping(); }
    }
}
```

**CsaLoginStateDbContext**

```
public class CsaLoginStateDbContext : SagaDbContext
{
    public CsaLoginStateDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<ISagaClassMap> Configurations
    {
        get { yield return new CsaLoginPMStateMapping(); }
    }
}
```

The old version of the app used AutoFac, and the registration was done like this:

```
builder.Register(x =>
    EntityFrameworkSagaRepository<OrderPMState>.CreateOptimistic(() => new OrderStateDbContext(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DB"))))
    .As<ISagaRepository<OrderPMState>>().SingleInstance();

builder.Register(x =>
    EntityFrameworkSagaRepository<CsaLoginPMState>.CreateOptimistic(() => new CsaLoginStateDbContext(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DB"))))
    .As<ISagaRepository<CsaLoginPMState>>().SingleInstance();
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a `DbContext`, you should be using one of the two configuration methods that are specifically designed for use with `DbContext`.

```cs
 busCfg.AddSagaStateMachine<CsaLoginPM, CsaLoginPMState>()
    .EntityFrameworkRepository<CsaLoginPMState>(efConfig =>
    {
        efConfig.ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Optimistic;

        efConfig.AddDbContext<DbContext, CsaLoginStateDbContext>((provider,builder) =>
        {
            builder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DB"), m =>
            {
                m.MigrationsAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
                m.MigrationsHistoryTable($"__{nameof(CsaLoginStateDbContext)}");
            });
        });
    });
```

Or you can add the DbContext separately and use that existing DbContext in the saga:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<CsaLoginStateDbContext>(builder =>
    builder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DB"), m =>
    {
        m.MigrationsAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
        m.MigrationsHistoryTable($"__{nameof(CsaLoginStateDbContext)}");
    }));

services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddSagaRepository<JobSaga>()
        .EntityFrameworkRepository(r =>
        {
            r.ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Optimistic;
            r.ExistingDbContext<CsaLoginStateDbContext>();
        });
});
```

This is all covered [in the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/efcore.html).

Comment: Hi Chris, i tried using the AddDbContext as show on https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/efcore.html , but neither AddDbContext or ExistingDbContext exists on IEntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryConfigurator<Saga>. 
Running Masstransit.AspNetCore/7.3.1, Masstransit.EntityFramework/7.3.1, Masstransit.RabbitMQ/7.3.1

Comment: They do, not sure why they don't for you. There are plenty of [samples](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ForkJoint/blob/master/src/ForkJoint.Api/Startup.cs#L102) doing it.

Comment: They are there if I use the Masstransit.EntityFrameworkCore package instead like in the samples you linked. But according to the docs, they should also be present with the Masstransit.EntityFramework package. Got any samples for regular EF?

Comment: Upgraded the app to use EntityFrameworkCore instead. Now things work.